# Google App Script : Retrieve value of a cell that is a formula, script is returning [0.0]

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I actually can't believe that I'm asking for something as simple as this, but anyway.

I have a report hub, with entries to complete, and I'd like to get everyone's number of entries left and send a Slack message. My issue here is that the values I get are simply a list of [0.0], [0.0], ect...

Here's my code :

```
function Values() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("Summary!B7:B28");
var data = range.getValues();


Logger.log(data)}
```

And the Output:
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]

the original data is something like that:

| Names (ColA) | Entries (ColB) |
| --- | --- |
| NAME1 | 47 |
| NAME2 | 150 |

Note that the values of entries are actually a formula (=SUM()).

I thought I could simply retrieve the data from col B, and use an index, and then do a loop that would look like this :

```
function Values() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange("Summary!B7:B28");
    var data = range.getValues();
    data.forEach(SendMessage);
    }

function SendMessage(val, index){
    var rtext = "";
    var rname = "";
    
    if(val > 0) {
     switch(index) {
      case 0: 
        rtext = "";
        rname = "";
        break;
      case 1:
        rtext = "";
        rname = "";
        break;
        default: return false;}}

// here the rest of my script to send slack messages//
}
```

What I found strange is the fact that even if I try to a simple =IMPORTRANGE within the sheet, for the same range, it also returns 0s. SO my main issue may be the source file.

I really hope someone can help me there, because I'm lost :)

Comment: What's the output of a formula `=Summary!B7*1`?

Comment: i'm not sure to understand fully, but i put this formula in a cell on my sheet, and the output is the expected number.
I actually tried before to simply recreate the range using `=Summary!B7`, after trying the `=IMPORTRANGE` method that failed, and I had the expected number as well, but when I tried the same code over this new range, I still had 0.0 as the output.

Comment: Where are the numbers coming from? Are they entered by a human manually?

Comment: No that's the thing, it's a lot of `=COUNTIF` that are then added with `=SUM()` and those =SUM() create my column

Comment: Were there any Google finance formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function Values() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("Summary!B7:B28");
  var data = range.getDisplayValues();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(data))
}
```

Comment: the output is still : `[["0"],["0"],["0"],["0"],["0"],["0"],["0"],["0"],["0"],["0"],["0"],["0"],["0"],["0"],["0"],["0"],["0"],["0"],["0"],["0"],["0"],["0"]].`    :(

Comment: It worked fine for me.  Please provide a table of your data for that range.  If I can't reproduce your output then you have not provide a [mcve]

Comment: Hey, for a reason that is still unknown to me, I've tried again this morning, and it works. Thanks for you help